# Graph limit with no 4 cycles

Tags: graph-theory

We know that there is an upper bound on the number of edges (as a function of vertices) with no 4 cycles.(on $ex(n,C_{4})$)

But how do we estimate a lower bound for it? (i.e. a good estimation for the number of edges the lowest upper bound of $ex(n, C_{4})$ must be greater than, e.g. e=3 is an obvious lower bound but we want a good one)

(At the lecture we did it using finite geometries but I can't remember how it went.)

Comment: What ist the upper bound?

Comment: @JMoravitz no, x<ex$(n,C_{4})$<y. We know a good lower bound on y, we want to find a good upper bound on x.

Comment: So, looking up notation, my understanding is that $EX(n,C_4)$ is the set of extremal graphs on $n$ vertices with no $C_4$ subgraph, and $ex(n,C_4)=|e(H)|$ with $H\in EX(n,C_4)$, so instead of asking for the smallest number of edges of a $C_4$-free graph, you are asking for the smallest number of edges for a $C_4$-free graph who if you were to add any missing edge would create a $C_4$ subgraph?  [This excerpt from a book seems to answer the question](http://www.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~jukna/EC_Book_2nd/sample/44-49.pdf), showing that the upper bound given is tight.

Comment: @JMoravitz I thought of an other upper bound which was not tight, that's why I asked the question, but this aswers it, thanks.